# How to compare two date in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

How can I convert date value into format of `dd-MM-yyyy` in SQL? I have stored date into database in `varchar(10)` format. Now want to compare date from `1-05-2015` to `31-06-2015`.

Query is :

```
select date
from dates
where date >='1-05-2015' and date <='10-06-2015'
```

I need help in Crystal report.
How can i remove blank line in crystal report 2008?

it returns only **(same result in use of between)**

1. 1-06-2015
2. 10-06-2015
3. 1-07-2015

I cannot use **[Format Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505.aspx)** because 2005 not support. I tried **[Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx)** method but not helpful.

Comment: Why do you store dates as strings in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this, if you store date as string, to convert it to DATE

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Then he has to check whether the string is 10 chars or 9... if 9, then add 0 to the beginning.

Comment: It would need to convert to DATETIME, I don't think SQL 2005 has a DATE data type.

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember whether the CONVERT was exactly like it is now, but you can try

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy -- Needed if date format on database server is different so the start and end date string values 01-05-2015 and 10-06-2015 can be converted automatically with the custom format
select date from dates where CONVERT(Date, date, 105) >='01-05-2015' and CONVERT(Date, date, 105) <='10-06-2015'
```

I would suggest not to store dates as varchar(10) but as Date or DateTime.
In addition I would use yyyy-MM-dd format, which can be interpreted regardless of whatever setting so you don't need the SET DATEFORMAT. 
So if you always store dates as date you can do (among other features):

```
select date from dates where date >= '2015-05-01' and date <= '2015-06-10'
```

Comment: Very right what you say. BTW, look how he stores the day component: It 1 or 2 digits. That won't work with the convert statement. You need to clean up the days first.

Comment: I can't imagine that's a requirement, since day is 1 digit and month is 2 digits. Didn't you use nvarchar(10) just because you don't know how easy it is to use date and thought nvarchar(10) is easier? You can see when setting date as '2015-06-10' SQL Server will convert it automatically to a date if it knows it needs a date.

Comment: If you really need to store date as varchar(10) then make it 10 long always, so do day in 2 digits. Save the date as yyyy-MM-dd too, so you can use both CAST as CONVERT to make a date, so you can apply all date functions/comparisons easily.

Comment: giving error                                                                                             The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other comments that dates stored in a proper date format are the best way to go, but sometimes changing the database isn't feasible.

Here's some code that will convert the date from your string format to datetime, assuming the month and year are always 2 and 4 characters, with the day being the only variable length.

Note, I changed the dates in the where statement from '1-05-2015' to '2015-05-01' and '10-06-2015' to '2015-06-10'.

```
select date
       , cast(right(date, 4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(date, charindex('-', date)+1, 2)+'-'+left(date, charindex('-', date)-1) as datetime) as converted_date
from dates
where
     cast(right(date, 4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(date, charindex('-', date)+1, 2)+'-'+left(date, charindex('-', date)-1) as datetime)
         >= cast('2015-05-01' as datetime)
     and cast(right(date, 4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(date, charindex('-', date)+1, 2)+'-'+left(date, charindex('-', date)-1) as datetime)
         <= cast('2015-06-10' as datetime)
```

Comment: thanks for response . but solve it by  some change in database filed. i changed data type varchar(30) to datetime. and problem solved. it will change all source code.   i will try your code thanks . bye

Comment: when i try it  give me a error                                                                         " ---   The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.--"

Comment: It could be some day or month is parsed incorrectly. You could remove the cast and break the year-month-day into columns, then check the data to make sure it's correct. Like this: select right(date, 4) as split_year, SUBSTRING(date, charindex('-', date)+1, 2) as split_month, left(date, charindex('-', date)-1) as split_day
from dates

Answer (score 0):

I can convert varchar to datetime in sql 2014 using the following code

ALTER TABLE table_you_want
ALTER COLUMN column_you_want DATETIME

Well i am not sure whether 2005 supports it or not.
hope it helps..!!1

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I had 2005 installed on my machine and i got results.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0bc2/1)

Let me know if this doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to date type with style:

```
select date 
from dates
where convert(date, date, 103) between '20150501' and '20150610'
```

Never keep dates as strings, numerics as strings etc. Use appropriate types, which will keep you far from problems like this.